Bluetooth audio rerouting in mobile app
I am sure many people have encountered this problem: I have a pair of headphones that are paired with several sender devices via Bluetooth, such as my computer, my mobile phone and the BT transceiver attached to my stereo. Since at least my mobile and my computer are basically always switched on, it is anyone's guess which device the headphones will connect to when I switch them on. Often I need to disable BT on one or more devices in order to direct the connection to the desired device. This is an obvious inconvenience, so I wonder if there is a mobile app that could help out with selecting which device the headphones should listen to. Maybe like so:

The headphones are only paired with the mobile.
The mobile is also paired with all sending devices.
The mobile app keeps a list of all sending devices and allows the user to select which one should send to the phones.
After selection, the app redirects the signal from the selected sending device to the headphones.

Is there already such an app? I have searched App Store but haven't found anything useful. Or can this even be realised without an app? Or is it technically impossible to devise such an app? If the answer to all questions above is "no", then I give away this idea for free to the interested developer :)
